# How can I get rid of an instance once and for all?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, instance

I have an **instance of an object - how can I get rid of it?**

Imagine this:

```
item1 = new MyItem( 123, "Test Item", "I am a test item" );
item2 = item3 = item1;
item1 = null;
```

I create an instance of *MyItem* and use it all over the place in my code (so there are multiple references to it in different scripts). But now I want to say: *This item no longer exists!*

If I set only one of them to null, the instance continues to exist and the other references still point to it.

**Is there a way to destroy the instance once and for all, so all references will be null?**

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve? Setting a variable to null that is never referenced again, does not do anything.

Comment: If you think you need this then you're already doing something wrong.

Comment: What I'm doing is this: I have a large amount of items and a singleton to access the list of items. Whenever anything in my program needs to work with an item it grabs a reference from the list. All of this is fed from an external DB. If an item gets updated the sync-script changes it on the singleton and every other script knows about it automatically. However: if an item gets deleted on the DB and I set the item to null on the singleton, no one else ever learns about it. That's why I was wondering if there's an easy way to clear all references and let everything know that this item is gone.

Comment: I guess I could just add:
    bool isDeleted = false; 
and change that as needed?

Comment: The issue seems to be that after _"it grabs a reference from the list"_ that reference is cached (for too long). Just don't do that.

Comment: Are there performance constraints against grabbing the item each time it's needed, rather than caching it?

Answer (score 3):

(1) You should look for `WeakReference` class. This way you can 'hold' an instance without incrementing their refcount. But this makes your software more complicated and prone to error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx

---

(2) You could create a wrapper, with an `IsAvailable` property, that will hold one instance.

Comment: I guess I could just add a wasDeleted property or field that I set to true before I set the item reference to null, and check that every time a script wants to access its reference of the item?

Comment: Yes, don't forget to lock if you cross-thread access your objects.

Comment: The WeakReference offers no solution here.